# Spring3's @Configuration cannot @Inject component-scanned beans

Tags: spring, configuration, dependency-injection, spring-3

This is my app.xml :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="destiny.web" />
<context:annotation-config/>
```

And there is a `Dao`(interface) , and `DaoImpl` (annotated with `@Repository`) inside destiny.web package.

There is another Spring3's destiny.web.AppConfig class :

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig
{
  @Inject
  private Dao daoImpl

  public AppConfig()
  {
    System.out.println("dao = " + daoImpl);
  }
}
```

It prints 'null' , why ?

I am sure all these beans/configuration/repositories are scanned. But it seems @Configuration doesn't know other scanned beans . Did I miss anything ?

I try to solve it by @ImportResource :

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:app.xml")
public class AppConfig
```

But it seems causing cyclic bean scan and throws this exception :

```
{main} org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Only one AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor may exist within the context.
Offending resource: class path resource [app.xml]
```

How to solve it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring will `invoke constructor firstly` `before inject / autowiring` the other component. therefore  your dao is null while you print at the constructor, because the `dao still not injected yet`.

Have a try to create test application for your configapp.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("stackoverflow.xml");

        AppConfig appConfig = context.getBean(AppConfig.class);
        appConfig.getConfig("smtp.host");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it also with the annotation `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject`?

Comment: I had to move out a bean config from the `@Configuration` file into `applicationContext.xml` but I still had other beans that referenced it within the `@Configuration` file. By using the `@Autowired` suggestion given here, I was able to successfully circumvent the problem. Its a good answer/suggestion.